Is God being just by sending Christian murderers to Heaven?
Let's say that a Christian serial killer has murdered many people who happened to not be Christians. Would God be just by sending the Christian serial killer to Heaven, while sending his victims to Hell?
I am looking for answers from the perspective of Christians who believe that Hell exists (non-universalists).

Why would God be sending these people to heaven or hell? Is being murdered a sin? Is being a murderer a virtuous act?

Compare with a baby that keeps its parents awake at night, soils its diapers, etc. Eventually it learns better, and changes its attitude and behaviour. Do you think it should be punished as an adult for what it did as a baby?
¶ If the killer eventually understands his sin and truly repents (changes his mind, character, and behaviour) he is no longer a serial killer. What would be the point of punishing him?
¶ It is one's current and future character that count. Forgiveness, not desire for vengeance and punishment, are part of a good character.

If God were to judge solely by an individual's sins, no one would be Saved. Instead, we are Saved by Grace, through Faith in Christ. Since that is the case, why does it matter what particular sins an individual has committed?

This is an hypothetical question and admits to so being :  'Let's say . . . . etc'. All hypothetical questions are, by definition, matters of opinion and are therefore off-topic on any academic platform such as Stack Exchange.

You cannot be a serial killer and your a Christian, you have to let go one and serve one master.

Historically, Christians have considered it a virtuous act to kill atheists, Jews, Muslims and pagans, but I don't think killing people will earn you a place in heaven. Can you cite the Bible to back up your position?

@CandidMoe, you are overgeneralizing, a specific Christian denomination during that age did what you claim and that is why the protestant reformation was born. Jesus preached love and said we should love our enemies and pray for those who persecute us. No one on this earth decides who lives and who dies.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany "With threefold horrible sins against God and men have these peasants loaded themselves, for which they have deserved a manifold death of body and soul." Luther, 1525, Peasant War.

@CandidMoe, I agree with you. The devil infiltrated the church and turned its members against themselves.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany. So, the devil infiltrated Luther? That's quite a statement.

@CandidMoe, all these divisions that resulted from an original parent church are not from God. Pentecostals, Evangelicals, Baptiss, Methodists, Trinitarians, Unitarians. God is not the author of divisions but the author of unity.

So, are you saying that there is only one true church from God, while the others (Pentecostals et all, if I understand) are from ... devil?

@CandidMoe, no am saying those divisions are not from God because God is not the author of confusion and chaos. No further comment. Peace.

This question is asking for an opinion.

"the perspective of Christians who believe that Hell exists" — Given that the word "hell" appears dozens of times in the Bible, what would be an example of a denomination that believes that "hell" doesn't exist? — I suspect that you actually mean people that don't believe in your personal (unspecified) understanding of what the word means.

While there are significant denominational differences over the doctrines of salvation, in general Christianity teaches these three truths:

Humanity is meant to exist in joyful loving relationship with God, our father and king
All of us have acted in rebellious autonomy against God (sin), and deserve his judgement and punishment
As an undeserved gift God forgives those who turn to him in faith, repentance, and a desire to be reconciled to him

There's lots of disagreement over the fate of those who die as infants, those with severe intellectual disabilities, etc. But for the common case of an adult with regular mental faculties, the truly just outcome is that we all deserve God's judgement. But because of God's exceeding mercy he offers reconciliation to any who would accept it.
So no, it's not just for God to bring the repentant serial killer into heaven. But it is merciful.

Mercy never (never, ever, ever) contradicts justice. That is what the Gospel is all about - for therein is the Righteousness of God revealed  . . . ..  that he is Just in justifying his people from their sins. His mercy is a just and righteous mercy. Your answer implies that it is not.

@NigelJ there is a justice in God's mercy that exists only because of Christ's substitution. I was writing here of natural justice, without the Gospel.

Maybe an edit, then, perhaps ?

Revelation chapter 21 verse 8 is perfectly clear that, in Heaven, there will be no murderers. All murderers will be in "the lake which burns with fire and brimstone, which is the second death."
But the Bible is equally clear that forgiven murderers will be in Heaven.
This hypothetical question is akin to the men who approached Jesus with a scenario of one woman having had seven husbands (one at a time, lawfully). They asked Jesus "Whose wife will she be in the resurrection?" He did not fall into that trap. Read Matthew 22:23-33, please.
To question whether God is just in any of his judgments (on this site) requires biblical reasons/evidence to back the question up, not hypothetical scenarios, which are off-topic and will likely result in this unfounded question being closed down.

I don't know where this angle of Christian vs non-Christian comes from. This must be a severe misunderstanding of christian doctrine. Even in the Old Testament, it is made very clear that repentace is a necessary condition for remission of sins.
Ezekiel 18:20-32 (KJV)

20 The soul that sinneth, it shall die. The son shall not bear the
iniquity of the father, neither shall the father bear the iniquity of
the son: the righteousness of the righteous shall be upon him, and the
wickedness of the wicked shall be upon him.
21 But if the wicked will turn from all his sins that he hath
committed, and keep all my statutes, and do that which is lawful and
right, he shall surely live, he shall not die.
22 All his transgressions that he hath committed, they shall not be
mentioned unto him: in his righteousness that he hath done he shall
live.
23 Have I any pleasure at all that the wicked should die? saith the
Lord God: and not that he should return from his ways, and live?
24 ¶ But when the righteous turneth away from his righteousness, and
committeth iniquity, and doeth according to all the abominations that
the wicked man doeth, shall he live? All his righteousness that he
hath done shall not be mentioned: in his trespass that he hath
trespassed, and in his sin that he hath sinned, in them shall he die.
25 ¶ Yet ye say, The way of the Lord is not equal. Hear now, O house
of Israel; Is not my way equal? are not your ways unequal?
26 When a righteous man turneth away from his righteousness, and
committeth iniquity, and dieth in them; for his iniquity that he hath
done shall he die.
27 Again, when the wicked man turneth away from his wickedness that he
hath committed, and doeth that which is lawful and right, he shall
save his soul alive.
28 Because he considereth, and turneth away from all his
transgressions that he hath committed, he shall surely live, he shall
not die.
29 Yet saith the house of Israel, The way of the Lord is not equal. O
house of Israel, are not my ways equal? are not your ways unequal?
30 Therefore I will judge you, O house of Israel, every one according
to his ways, saith the Lord God. Repent, and turn yourselves from all
your transgressions; so iniquity shall not be your ruin.
31 ¶ Cast away from you all your transgressions, whereby ye have
transgressed; and make you a new heart and a new spirit: for why will
ye die, O house of Israel?
32 For I have no pleasure in the death of him that dieth, saith the
Lord God: wherefore turn yourselves, and live ye.

In Christian doctrine, repentance is made possible through (the atonement of) Jesus Christ, and you can only really repent and be made whole through faith in Him. I assume that is safe enough to say in an ecumenical way, but of course I can't really speak for all denominations.
Making this about murder seems to be to make the example extreme. Non-christian murder victims are in no way special - I'd wager the majority of humans that have died have not been christian.
So really the question is twofold here:

Can murderers repent and be forgiven?
What happens to dead non-christians?

Mixing these two creates an emotional mix that doesn't really help, when in reality there's two relatively independent questions hidden in here.
None of these two questions can be answered by simply scoping the questions with "Christians that believe in Hell".

"when in reality there's two relatively independent questions hidden in here" — Good observation. (Though I suspect the OP doesn't realize that they are questions, already knowing the answers to each of them. A contradiction between the two unspecified beliefs then creates the question that was asked.)

First of all, no one who continues in sin(killing men made in the image of God) is born again regardless of whether they have Christian beliefs or not. A new born Christian is expected to keep the commandments of Jesus and one of those commandments is that ye shall not kill. Once someone is born again they are expected to resist all temptations to sin as it is written resist the devil and he will flee away from you.
1 John 3:9

No one born of God makes a practice of sinning, for God 's seed abides in him; and he cannot keep on sinning, because he has been born of God.

You cannot continue sinning and still profess to be a Christian, that kind of habit makes you a backslider. You were saved but out of the pleasure of unrighteousness, you went back to serve the world instead of God.

Technically, the command is to not murder. There is such a thing as a killing that is both permitted and even demanded by the Law. For example: an avenger of blood.

@RyanPierceWilliams, noted.

“For all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God” Romans 3:23, the “Believe in the Lord Jesus, and you will be saved” (Acts 16:31).

@CandidMoe, Amen. Believing is more about keeping his commandments, it is the only way we can express our love towards God.

This answer is from the point of view where the Kingdom of God is a physical place here on Earth during the Millennium following Christ's return.
Imagine you are resurrected in the Kingdom of God and Saint Paul is showing you around. You encounter Hitler, Stalin, Pol Pot, Attila the Hun, Judas, and a few other similarly hated people.
Do you want:

To see them all sent to Hell to be tortured and punished for all eternity?
To help each of them to understand his sin, to repent, and to receive salvation?

Which fate would bring you joy?
Which fate would you consider "just" for these killers?
Before you answer, realize that:

Saint Paul (AKA Saul of Tarsus, responsible for the persecution and deaths of Steven and countless other Christians) is one of those killers.
It is not they, but you, being judged.

The idea of forgiveness occurs throughout the Bible, the most explicit being in Matthew 6:

14 For if ye forgive men their trespasses, your heavenly Father will also forgive you:
15 But if ye forgive not men their trespasses, neither will your Father forgive your trespasses.


@CandidMoe, I've just added a scripture.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Even a universalist can answer this... Hi, I believe in Apokatatasis, that everyone will receive God's Love.
Now, God's love might be the loving fire of purification.... and that is hell.
Everyone goes to the same place that is to say "With God". How this serial killer or his victims will receive the love of God personally is subject to debate.
I would point out that the serial killer, cannot be a christian. Murder in the sense of a serial killer (that is to say, motiveless killing for the sake of killing) is incompatible with being christian. Even a priest would be obligated to stop you from committing this sin again, they would attempt to guide this person to turn themselves in... but ultimately they would do it themselves if the killer did not.
As for the victims... you only say they are not christian. Does not justify the serial killer. And we do not know if the actions, inner workings of the Holy Spirit, etc on those people will negatively affect their experience of the Love of God. We cannot know.

I really like your answers actually. They feel very Godly. I don't know how to explain it.

@ChessIce I appreciate the very high compliment. Thank you, and merry Christmas.

Merry Christmas!

Just because someone holds Christian beliefs does not mean that they are automatically saved - nor that one who doesn’t hold Christian beliefs is automatically damned. The scriptures are clear that we are judged and rewarded - for better or worse - by our deeds.
Of course, God is willing to forgive just about any sin providing we repent and act in accordance with that repentance. The scriptures say that it is those who persevere that will be saved.
King David is a central figure in the biblical narrative who is both said to have had a heart after God’s own AND who went onto commit murder (in an attempt to cover up his adultery). Though the Law called for his death - he repented and was spared (though not without consequence).
That said, a life long Christian who suddenly decides to go on a killing spree and who is killed in the act may find themselves in a precarious position come the judgment.
Ultimately, however, the scriptures maintain that mercy is greater than justice. Justice is good and holy, but it is not the ultimate good (which is love). We must understand that justice is a servant to love; not the master.

“Believe in the Lord Jesus, and you will be saved” (Acts 16:31). No strings attached.

@CandidMoe what you are doing is called cherry  picking. There is a wealth of scriptures that make it quite clear that more than a mere intellectual belief is necessary for salvation. James 2 explicitly calls out your error and addresses those who say such things as fools.

I'm not the one that invented cherry picking. I learn it from christians. The Bible always has a quote that supports your position, it's just a matter of finding it. Examples abound.

@CandidMoe the scriptures must be studied to be understood in context. You can take passages out of context in pretty much any work to make it appear to support a position it does not. Doing so doesn’t show a problem with the work in question but with the reading comprehension and intellectual honesty of the one cherry picking.

But you didn't quote from the Bible. "The scriptures are clear that we are judged and rewarded by our deeds" is a catholic proposition. Justificatio sola fide (or simply sola fide), meaning justification by faith alone, is a soteriological doctrine in Christian theology commonly held to distinguish the Lutheran and Reformed traditions of Protestantism, among others, from the Catholic church.

I’m happy to provide explicit references where requested. However, as I noted, the scriptures need to be studied to be understood. A summation of their teachings can be more helpful than isolated scripture references. And yes, the idea that we are judged by our deeds is very much scriptural. I am no Catholic. As one of many examples, read Romans 2:6-11

@CandidMoe says "I'm not the one that invented cherry picking.". No, but that doesn't justify using it yourself.

First part of question is Yes, If God does anything, it is always 'Just'.
And so, remains the rest of the rest of the question:
" .. by sending Christian murderers to Heaven?"
Since 'murderer' excludes killing which would be forgiven or pleasing, and it assumes that one knows the heart of the person and the relevant situation, and have sufficient virtue-grace of 'Judgement', as we see today that many powerful people operate above the law and as Thomas Aquinas argues may be killed, where many others would say the act is 'murder':
COMMENTARY ON THE SENTENCES, BOOK II, by Thomas Aquinas
I Sentences, Distinction 44, Question 2, Article 2, Whether Christians are bound to obey secular powers, especially tyrants'
"d 5. To the fifth argument the answer is that Cicero speaks of domination obtained by violence and ruse, the subjects being unwilling or even forced to accept it and there being no recourse open to a superior who might pronounce judgment upon the usurper. In this case he that kills the tyrant for the liberation of the country, is praised and rewarded."
It is possible to find yourself, or witness others suffering abuse with murderous intent where no appeal to Authority is possible without yourself suffering punishment and the abuser no punishment or possible reward, and even if you escape the situation the abuser would do similar to others, as in past resulted in their intension realized; suicide of victim.
Killing not in vengeance but in defense, seems Justified, where others would say "murder." It seems likely that some percentage of workplace and school shooting may fall into this category. The single targeted killing versions, not the random many, of course.
Others have argued that a practicing Christian cannot be a murderer, along with conditions of exceptions and related situations, and so I will suggest a unique Christian theoretical perspective I have not seen before.
I offer for your considerations the possibility that at the end of each day Jesus Comes with the Kingdom. And so, the moment after this and when we return to our last state of being, we each were forgiven (Jesus 'Paid' for our sins that day), or we had in the Eternity between moments in this reality, as '1 day here is 1000 years (of days) in Heaven.' In either case, Justice to God for our sins are paid.
I propose two Scripture passage to support this position.
John 1:50-51
"Jesus answered and said to him: Because I said unto thee, I saw thee under the fig tree, thou believest: greater things than these shalt thou see. And he saith to him: Amen, amen I say to you, you shall see the heaven opened, and the angels of God ascending and descending upon the Son of man."
Luke 12:20-21
"But God said to him: Thou fool, this night do they require thy soul of thee: and whose shall those things be which thou hast provided? So is he that layeth up treasure for himself, and is not rich towards God."
And so, it is Known by Faith in Traditional Catholic Doctrine that a Perfect act of Contrition, or an Imperfect one followed by the Sacrament of Reconciliation, returns Grace and Life to soul, and perhaps the state of our souls is returned to neutral the moment of each new day - and so Judgment of the Day and any Justice to God payment is limited to that day's sins.
My answer is to the more general question then asked above - how can any Grave sinner under negative Judgement proceed forward and result entering into the Kingdom of God.

for Ray Butterworth answer, anyone already in the Kingdom of Heaven has been Judged and so belong there, so if Hitler or even Benjamin Netanyahu(!) is found there then who are we to Judge against God? And since Jesus Commands us to Love (willing the Good) all others as self how can anyone there in His Kingdom will Hell of any other? And Muder is not only against Divine Positive law but Natural Law.

Sadly, it seems that - by my count - 3 Answers of (-1) score, out of 12 Answers to 12 Questions here has somehow blocked my ability to Answer questions. So, the moderators anti-Catholics, and GramerNazis will not have me to kick-around for a while.
